# Double Click to open file directory from an item in listview

Tags: c#

I hope that there is a very straightforward way to allow a user to do a `Doubleclick` event on either items inside a listview.

The items in my listview happens to have a filepath, so if possible, i want to draw out that filepath from the item that i've selected and open up as a windows to show where the file is located. Something like that...is that complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ItemActivate event on the ListView: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate.aspx)

From there you can get the selected item and open an window.